# Why I have no permission ？

Tags: find

[image]

So I execute the find command in the picture, why there are so many permission denied? I am a root user. Just this problem.

Comment: Please, [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).

Comment: You're copying _everything_ owned by root on the whole system down into `/root/results`, including the contents of `/root/results`? Why? Also `/proc` is not a directory of ordinary files.

Comment: `/proc` exists only in memory and is virtual so you can't copy it! The error is normal!

Comment: OK, I gotta it. I am beginning learning linux , so I copy a example of command find in my computer to check it.Then the problem above occured.Now I got the reason.Thanks so much.

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen  Please don't post answers as comments!  **;-)**  Ping me after you've answered and I'll come back to upvote.

Comment: @fabby done added an answer!

Answer (score 3):

The `/proc` and also the `/sys` exists only in memory and is virtual so you can't copy it!

> These are pseudo−filesystems because they exist totally in memory; if you look at the disk partition when the system is not running, there will be only an empty directory which is used as a mount point.

So the error is *absolutely normal!*

Comment: And edited and upvoted!

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question.

Comment: Can those directories be copied as OP is trying to?